# Do I need to rewrite this SQL query in Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Products are on sale on a website in a limited time period.

Each sale starts at a `DATE`, ends at a `DATE`, and contains at least one product.

Each product is associated with the id# of the sale it belongs to.

Sometimes there is a short timeframe which there are no products inside a sale, because the manager created the sale but has not finished associating products to the sale yet, so I have to filter out sales with no products inside when displaying the list of upcoming sales, or it will confuse users.

In my `Sale` model, I have come up with this as I'm not that familiar with ActiveRecord:

```
def upcoming_sales
    find_by_sql(["SELECT DISTINCT sales.* from sales, products WHERE products.sale_id = sales.id AND sales.start_at > ? AND sales.start_at < ? ORDER BY sales.start_at ASC", Time.now, (Time.now + END_AT)])
end
```

I believe the SQL above is standard ANSI SQL which should run on pretty much any database server, but can it be done with ActiveRecord instead?

Other than making it friendly to non-SQL users, are there any benefits in redoing it with ActiveRecord?

Which way is better, performance-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw SQL is difficult to maintain. Performance wise definitely raw sql is better, but consider the following benefits of `ActiveRecord`. You get a nice querying syntax, which is far more readable considering there are others who might need to modify your code. Also, `ActiveRecord` lets you be agnostic to the database engine to an extent which would not be possible with raw sql.

But, if you consider performance as your only bottleneck, then `ActiveRecord` falls behind. I would say, do a small research. The above query is a join query and definitely raw SQL will give you noticeable performance benefit. Lot of other things can be done to improve the performance of queries dramatically, like proper `indexing`, `caching`, `eager loading`(when need comes as sometimes eager loading actually makes the queries slow) etc. Before you ditch `ActiveRecord` make sure, it really is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can write custom SQL, but it's not advisable when AR works just fine (you'll get homogeneous clear code, DB-independent, ...):

```
def upcoming_sales
  select('DISTINCT sales.*').
    joins(:products).
    where(["sales.start_at > ? AND sales.start_at < ?", Time.now, Time.now + END_AT]).
    order("sales.start_at ASC")
end
```